# Any way to automatically modify Chef recipes to work with different cloud provider?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, rackspace-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Is there some way to take in a chef recipe (and then say it was used for AWS EC2) automatically change it to work on Rackspace or SoftLayer?

Edit: If this doesn't exist, how hard do you think it would be to create it from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

That really depends a great deal on the Cookbook.  The vast majority of cookbooks are completely unaware of whether they are run on bare metal, AWS, rackspace, etc.  They are typically far more concerned with what operating system they are running on.

So they answer, on a much lighter note, is that you send them to me along with a few hundred dollars, and I send them back to you "automatically" (and unchanged).

On a more serious note, if you can tell us what cookbook/s you have in mind, we could give you a better idea.

Comment: The hope would be that say someone has a cookbook that is designed to do something in particular (as you noted--unaware of whether it will be run on bm, aws, rackspace, softlayer, etc). It'd be useful to have a tool that could then automatically modify the script to work on a particular hosting provider (either from an api or via gui with drop-downs etc). Do you think anything like this exists or would be possible to create?

Comment: I'm sorry, but without a more specific use case, I really can't help.  My point was that such a tool shouldn't be needed.  Very few cookbooks do anything that is directly related to the hosting platform.  So unless your cookbook does something very cloud specific, like creating a load balancer, etc, it would not care where it was run, and would work across ANY cloud platform.  If it does do something specific, then the answer is to use the fog library rather than a specific cloud library.  But it would be very hard to use a tool to modify it for a different cloud otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what it is you want to do its also worth checking out the Knife plugins for the various Cloud vendors:

- SoftLayer Knife = https://github.com/softlayer/knife-softlayer
- AWS Knife = https://github.com/chef/knife-ec2
- RackSpace Knife = https://github.com/chef/knife-rackspace
- Google Knife = https://github.com/chef/knife-google
- Azure Knife = https://github.com/chef/knife-azure

Cheers
EJK

Answer (score 1):

A cookbook that is designed to do something (like for example install php) *doesn't* know how to do it for Rackspace, AWS, etc, specifically. That part is in your own installation.

An oversimplified explanation of it is that the cookbook tells chef what it wants done, and chef uses the knife (knife-rackspace, to pick one from the list) to do it.

Go read the chef documentation a bit more, install chefDK on your own system and run through some of the tutorials. You'll soon enough get the hang of it. I have a .kitchen.yml file I'm using here that uses the same cookbook to build two different OS platforms using two different providers. The determinant is what server I tell it to build: "kitchen converge xxxx" where xxxx is the name of the server I want to build. It'll use the same cookbook(s) to build the server, whether it's up in the cloud or in a virtualbox instance on my local machine.

And no, I didn't have to do any hoop-jumping to make it work across providers. Had to use some conditional logic to include the right package manager cookbooks (yum for CentOS and apt for Ubuntu, for example) but that's just in determining which cookbook to have on hand, not changing/converting any specific recipes.

The basic rule is if there's anything at all in the cookbook that's specific to a particular cloud provider (like Rackspace, AWS, etc.) You're Doing It Wrong. The cookbook should be agnostic. And if it's not, go find another one that is, because chances are there are other issues in that cookbook that you haven't found yet.